# I want split input string by "\n"

Tags: java

I want to split the input string by "\n", here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class toy_interpreter {

    public static String program;

    public static void getToyProgram() {

        Scanner prog1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the toy program");
        program = prog1.nextLine();

    }

    public static String[] splitList() {

        return program.split("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        getToyProgram();

        String[] parts = splitList();
        String part1 = parts[1];
        System.out.println(part1);      
    }
}
```

But the output shows that:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at toy_interpreter.main(toy_interpreter.java:36)

could you help me?

Comment: You are only reading one line `program = prog1.nextLine();` - why do you think you can split?

Comment: You are reading only one input line on your program, so there'll be only one `\n` in your input, thus one position on your array. if you want to receive multiple `Strings` from the user you should use a loop

Comment: You are reading only one input line on your program, so there'll be only one `\n` in your input, thus one position on your array. if you want to receive multiple `Strings` from the user you should use a loop

Comment: When you [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems?noredirect=1&lq=1) it you can see what causes the issue and why. Beware of Scanner, though, it is [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I can add multiple line and output it, but i can not output the result with index = 1 or 2 3 after program be splited.

Comment: @HenriqueSabino, nextLine consumes `\n` but [doesn't include](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) it in its return value. Scanner is tricky and nasty. It is **evil**.

Comment: but if i input “A = 2 \n B = 8 \n C = A + B \n C” , the output will do the same.

Comment: @gurioso That's right, forgot about that one, anyways, because they're reading one line only there'll be only 1 position in the array

Comment: @Henryli that's an interesting way of inputing the string, lol. Have you tried changing the split character? Like inputing "A = 2;B = 8;C = A + B;C" and splitting it by the semicolon

Comment: yes, i try to change" \n" to "n" , it can output a perfect result.

Comment: Maybe this can clarify something: usually when people talk about the character `'\n'` (decimal 10 on the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), meaning **new line**), which is one character, rather than the string `"\n"` (ascii 92 110), which are two characters. Note: `'` vs `"`. Nobody uses "\n" as a record separator btw. If you do perhaps you arrive at @sidgate's approach, but I guess, you don't want to get there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a singular line at prog1.nextLine(), so I am not sure how many objects you expect in the array, but I feel from your naming convention and the error code that you might not realize that arrays start at [0], not [1].

In your case split() will save your entire line to [0]. Since it ends on the lineend, the length of the array is 1, as split() will not create another String for an empty element. You are trying to access [1], which is the second element of the array, which does not exist. Hence the ArrayOutOfBoundsException!

If you wanted to save multiple lines to *program*, make sure not to just use the = sign. It'll overwrite your previous String with the new one. Trying using *program +=* for repeated uses, or use the .concat() method. Java will handle both the same during compile anyhow. For that matter, you might want to look into the *StringBuilder* class if you plan to build a multi-line string from user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] splitList() {
    return program.split("\\\\n");
}
```

`split` function takes a regex. Your input has a backslash that needs to be escaped in the input. And this backslash again has to be escaped for regex